# When should we have regular chat sessions?

Tags: discussion, chat

I'd like to set up a regular series of chat sessions, to allow us to discuss events on the site or in the world of physics, and to boost our community spirit. Or something like that. Anyway, what time works for people? Please upvote any times that work for you, downvote any that don't, and if nothing works, post a suggestion as a new answer.

---

**UPDATE** in case you're too lazy to scroll down (I'm not judging!): the suggestion seems to have enough support, so we will be starting regular biweekly chat sessions *next* Tuesday, July 3, at [4 PM UTC](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?iso=20120626T17). It's now listed on the [chat room's schedule](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/71/the-h-bar?tab=schedule). If you're going to be there, feel free to click the link and register!

Comment: :D I like this idea! I think it is excellent!

Comment: Thanks @Aarthi :-) If only our community shared your enthusiasm...

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky you can use [this](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?iso=20120626T17) to show more effectively the difference in the various Time Zones. I chose, as an example based on your answer, next Monday -  June 26th, 5 PM. (You can modify easily in the URL itself: 20120626T17 = 2012 06 26 T17.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suggestion: 4-5 PM UTC on Tuesdays (noon-1 PM EDT). Upvote if this works for you.