# Should we stop having biweekly chat sessions?

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-events

For about five years we've been having chat sessions every two weeks - they [started](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/when-should-we-have-regular-chat-sessions) as a way to build up activity in the chat room, but it's also been a nice way to engender a sense of community between chat and the main site and to discuss issues of general interest. But for quite a while we've had very little to talk about in the chat sessions. Should we just cancel the regular schedule, and only hold sessions as needed when there is something big to discuss?

Comment: I don't understand what a down/upvote is supposed to mean here. Does it convey agreement or disagreement? There are as of now +2/-2 votes, and I have no idea what those users think. Do you think we should stop having biweekly chat sessions or not? **please verbalise your opinion instead of just voting!**

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Downvotes mean we should not stop having biweekly chat sessions. Upvotes mean we should stop having biweekly chat sessions.

Comment: _yikes, whoa!_ thought you liked em! seems like some, even many meetings have been quite lively. agreed others (eg last one) dont "fire". think its ok to have regular meetings without trying to figure out agendas beforehand, theres really nothing lost at all in those cases. also think agendas dont nec have to be on site mgt. the physics chat mtg is defn quite unique SE wide but think thats a feature, not a bug. it could be biweekly is too often? but seemed like an ok interval to me. maybe a different time might work better? the current mtg time does conflict with US work hours :|

Answer (score 2):

No! A thousand times no!

I can't often make them, because, well, school. But I love it when I make chat sessions, and I think that while there've been some quiet ones (the one today, I see, was only a few messages, which probably inspired this post) they overall have been a great thing. Just because something fails once or twice doesn't mean you chuck the baby with the bathwater.

So...maybe we add a community ad (heheh, puns) or try to otherwise spread the word - in other chat rooms, or whatever. Or, as vzn mentioned in the comments, we could change the time of the session and see what happens. Just don't end these sessions.